# Get Spacemacs/Emacs GUI version to recognize nix-shell environment

Tags: shell, emacs, development-environment, nix

I do my development in a Nix shell (create a default.nix file in my project root and then run `nix-shell .` to give me a shell with access to the project dependencies).

Spacemacs is my main editor, but when I try to run the GUI version via `emacs &` I don't have access to the programs in my nix-shell (if I were in a Ruby on Rails project for example, and Ruby was declared as a dependency in my `default.nix`, I would have no syntax highlighting in Spacemacs because the GUI version of Emacs doesn't see my Nix-shell dependencies).  If I run `:!which ruby`, it can't even find the `which` command.

Right now, I'm running spacemacs via `emacs -nw` and just using it from the console, but I would really like to be able to use the GUI editor and get the full colorschemes available rather than being limited to the ones that look nice in 256 color mode.  It's also quicker for me to switch between the terminal and the editor than between tmux panes or terminal splits to get to my CLI editor.

```
with import <nixpkgs> {}; {
  cannyFreeRadicalEnv = stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
    name = "rails-project-env";
    version = "0.1";
    src = ./.;
    buildInputs = [
        stdenv
        ruby_2_2_2
        bundler
        zlib
        postgresql94
        sqlite
        zsh
        git
        nodejs-0_12
    ];
  };
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by running space emacs in daemon mode.
https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon

in the directory with default.nix:

`nix-shell .
emacs --daemon
emacsclient -c -a emacs`

Comment: Does this open a while new window or buffer? What if I have multiple nix-shell projects? Will each one run in its own window? Can it be made to run in their own buffers instead?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai This is no longer how I use space emacs. I do what  Netsu does now. The only trick is that you need to also add emacs to your shell.nix if you want if you want it to be able to find all the libraries that your shell.nix includes.

Answer (score 4):

You can run your GUI Emacs as

```
setsid nix-shell . --command "emacs" &> /dev/null
```

Also see discussion about `nix-shell` [integration](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/610) to `flycheck` and `ghc-mode`.

---

**Tip:** you can use alias for this in your *.zshrc* or *.bashrc*

```
run-nix-emacs () {
  setsid nix-shell . --command "emacs" &> /dev/null
}

alias ne='run-nix-emacs'
```

Comment: I tried this out.  As the answer is, running `:!which ruby` still says it cannot find the `which` command, and my Ruby configuration layer is still unavailable because the irb and ruby commands can't be found.  I'll read through the link you provided to the flycheck and ghc-mod discussion, but my sense is that this is probably an Emacs with Nix issue rather than a general Nix issue.

Comment: @josiah, did you install `which`?

Comment: not system-wide, but within the Nix-shell development environment, which is available because it's part of nixpkgs.stdenv.

Comment: Seems like it's really Spacemacs issue. My Emacs even with GUI just work in this case.

Comment: I'll dig in and try to get some more info on the issue

Comment: Is this not affected by: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/2294

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [this nix-shell.el](https://github.com/emacs-pe/nix-mode/blob/master/nix-shell.el). My [fork](https://github.com/analyticd/nix-mode) of it provides some configuration examples. While direnv integration to Emacs works, it is very slow. Not that this is faster, but it happens when you execute M-x nix-shell-activate and so you control when the latency happens. This becomes import if for instance you have a shell.nix in your org-directory for org source blocks in a multi-language environment and do not always want the direnv delay when you are opening an org file. Mario's nix-shell.el should be more widely known. [Here](https://github.com/travisbhartwell/nix-emacs/issues/40) is where I discovered it.